# Paypal MVC dynamic payments and notification

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal

I have not used the paypal service at all but I have done some research. I am however not sure about a few things. I understand you get various options, from simple buttons to a pretty versatile api.

My questions are 
What is the easiest way to implement dynamic payments? By dynamic payments I mean the user must be able to type in any amount and then that is the amount he pays for. He is not paying for a product but rather some service.

How then will I be notified of the payment and how will I be able to link this back to a user on my site. In other words as soon as the user made his contribution I want to know that he did so immediately so that the site can correspond accordingly.

This is the only functionality that I need. I do not need any shopping carts and those kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

What is "easiest" is relative to your skill level and the tools you're using, but generally speaking, a basic HTML form using [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) will get that done for you without the need for any API calls or anything like that.

The best thing for automating post-transaction tasks is [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  It will POST transaction data to a listener script you setup on your server and you can process the data however you need.  This includes payments, refunds, disputes, cleared e-checks, etc.